# How to have two headphones (one usb, one not) play sound at the same time?

Tags: 12.04, headphones

I've tried installing pulseaudio but it doesn't let me do two headphones at once. Thanks.

Comment: You would have to use jack. One sound card or two ? same playback or different audio streams  ?

Comment: I don't have a sound card (motherboard has built in sound)

Comment: You should probably identify your hardware and update your question. Use Jack ;)